# How to know if an answer is still relevant?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answered-questions

Looking for example at questions [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) and [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace), both questions include in their answers the use of ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager). But then there is this question [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it) where in the answer an experienced user says that using ccsm is outright "dangerous".

How would one go about finding out if an answer is still relevant (even if the answer has lots of upvotes), for example if ccsm has recently became stable, or if some other answer is no longer viable because of some other change, especially if (sometimes) the questions and answers have no mention of the versions used?

In some cases it might be just a matter of testing it out, but other times it might be a big risk of really breaking something.

Since I for example at the moment don't have enough rep to go comment an answer and ask if the case is still as stated, should I then just post a new question like "Is ccsm safe to use yet?" or "What other ways are there to achieve x other than y?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the answer says, `ccsm` can be prone to accidental breakage if you do something it's not designed for. So is `rm`. You would never consider suggesting you remove `rm` though, would you?

I stand by my suggestions of `ccsm`. It's a tool that can be poorly used but I think my directions are explicit enough to make it the best solution to that problem.

---

In the wider scope, yes you would either test it yourself or if you had concerns about the safety of doing so, you can:

- Comment on the answer (probably preferred if the user is still active - their profile should tell you this)
- Ask in Chat.
- Start a new question on the main site (or here). A question like that would be on-topic on both sites.